# Are Outlook 2007 File Picker Dialogs customizable?

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

I am currently trying to figure out how to customize the Outlook 2007 file picker dialogs (such as the "Insert File" dialog for adding an attachment to an email) to include some new functionality. For other applications that use the `GetSaveFileName` and `GetOpenFileName` functions from the Win32 API, I was able to use the `OFN_ENABLEHOOK` method to add my customizations.  Since Outlook doesn't use those comdlg32 API functions, this method doesn't work here.

Does anyone know how to do something like this in Outlook? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question: Outlook 2007 on Windows Vista and 7 uses the `IFileDialog` interfaces, which can be customized / hooked using the `IFileDialog::Advise` function along with an implementation of the `IFileDialogEvents` interface.  On Windows XP, since the `IFileDialog` interfaces do not exist, Outlook uses a custom dialog that looks like the common controls dialog, but in fact is completely custom code.